# MSSQL - How do reassociate a user login from a restored db?

Tags: sql-server

I restored a MSSQL DB on my machine but the user cant login.
How do I reassociate this user to a login on my machine?

Comment: Google found 10 answers to this question in all of 4 seconds of work.  It's also an off-topic question.

Comment: Are you trying to log in to the database using Management Studio, or are you trying to log in to an application that stores its credentials in the database? Or, what I'm trying to say is: can't you log in to the DB itself, or can't you log in to an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exec sp_change_users_login Report
```

will tell you about any that are unlinked

```
exec sp_change_users_login Auto_Fix, 'YourUserName'
```

will fix them